# Wiring up CollectionChanged and PropertyChanged (Or : Why do some WPF Bindings not refresh?)

Tags: wpf, data-binding, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

WPF DataBindings used to make me happy. One thing I've stumbled over just now is that at some point they just don't refresh as intented. Please take a look at the following (fairly simple) code:

```
<Window x:Class="CVFix.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="300">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Persons}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedPerson}"
                  x:Name="lbPersons"></ListBox>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedPerson.Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

The Code behind for the XAML:

```
using System.Windows;
namespace CVFix
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public ViewModel Model { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Model = new ViewModel();
        this.DataContext = this.Model;
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, here's the ViewModel classes:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace CVFix
{
  public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    private PersonViewModel selectedPerson;

    public PersonViewModel SelectedPerson
    {
        get { return this.selectedPerson; }
        set
        {
            this.selectedPerson = value;

            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedPerson"));
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel> Persons { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        this.Persons = new ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel>();
        this.Persons.Add(new PersonViewModel() { Name = "Adam" });
        this.Persons.Add(new PersonViewModel() { Name = "Bobby" });
        this.Persons.Add(new PersonViewModel() { Name = "Charles" });
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  }
}

public class PersonViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.name; }
        set
        {
            this.name = value;
            if(this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Name;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

What I'd want to happen: As I select an entry from the ListBox and modify its Name in the TextBox, the list gets updated to display the new value.

What happens : nothing. And that is the correct behaviour, If I'm any judge.
I made sure that the SelectedItem's PropertyChanged is fired, but that does (of course) not cause CollectionChanged to be fired.

To fix this, I created an ObservableCollection-derived class that has a public OnCollectionChanged method, see here :

```
public class PersonList : ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel>
{
    public void OnCollectionChanged()
    {
        this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs( NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset ));
    }
}
```

I access this from the ViewModel's constructor, as described below:

```
    public ViewModel()
    {
        PersonViewModel vm1 = new PersonViewModel()
        {
            Name = "Adam"
        };
        PersonViewModel vm2 = new PersonViewModel()
        {
            Name = "Bobby"
        };
        PersonViewModel vm3 = new PersonViewModel()
        {
            Name = "Charles"
        };
        vm1.PropertyChanged += this.PersonChanged;

        this.Persons = new PersonList();


        this.Persons.Add(vm1);
        this.Persons.Add(vm2);
        this.Persons.Add(vm3);
    }

    void PersonChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Persons.OnCollectionChanged();
    }
```

It works, but it's not a clean solution. My next idea would be creating a derivate of ObservableCollection that does the wiring up automatically in a CollectionChanged-handler.

```
public class SynchronizedObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T> where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                {
                    foreach (INotifyPropertyChanged item in e.NewItems)
                    {
                        item.PropertyChanged += this.ItemChanged;
                    }
                    break;
                }

            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                {
                    foreach (INotifyPropertyChanged item in e.OldItems)
                    {
                        item.PropertyChanged -= this.ItemChanged;
                    }
                    break;
                }
        }
        base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
    }

    void ItemChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }
}
```

The question is : is there a better way to do this? Is this really necessary?

Thanks a lot in advance for any input!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not necessary at all.  The reason your sample is failing is subtle, but quite simple.

If you don't provide WPF with a template for a data item (such as the `Person` objects in your list), it'll default to using the `ToString()` method to display.  That's a member, not a property, and so you get no event notification when the value changes.

If you add `DisplayMemberPath="Name"` to your listbox, it'll generate a template that binds properly to the `Name` of your person - which will then update automatically as you'd expect.

Comment: Thanks a lot, yours is the most descriptive Answer (The others being correct in the very same way).

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is to do with your ToString() override on PersonViewModel.  If you remove this, and use a DataTemplate on the ListBox instead, then you should get your expected behaviour:

```
<Window x:Class="CVFix.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Persons}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedPerson}"
              x:Name="lbPersons">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>            
    </ListBox>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedPerson.Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

add `DisplayMemberPath="Name"` to `ListBox`. The problem is you are relying on `ToString()` to display person's name and not any property. That is why raising `PropertyChanged` does not make any difference. From now on, don't use a method to evaluate any value in Bindings.